# Redirect User when they click Menu Option

Tags: php, menus, redirect, navigation

I am setting up a new website where I am managing a small amount of clients. I have created a menu page that when the user is logged out it basically just tells the user to login. But I want to code for when a user is logged in and clicks on that same menu page, I want it to redirect to a private page I have created for them. Each individual already has a private page. The URL for each private page is "example.com/private-page/username/. If the URL doesn't exist for an individual I just want the code to go back to the original menu page not a nonexistent page.

I have tried different ways including using meta to refresh the page to the other url. I can't figure what exactly isn't working. I am typing the code on the function.php

```
 function get_page_by_slug( $slug ) {
        if( $pages = get_pages() )
            foreach( $pages as $page )
                if( $slug === $page->post_name ) return true;
                return false;
   } 

   function userredirect() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $slug = $current_user->user_login;
        if( is_user_logged_in() && is_page('Menu Page') ){
             if( get_page_by_slug($slug) ){
             }wp_redirect('https://example.com/private-page/'.$slug.'/');
                 exit;
        }
    }
```

Nothing Happens when I go to the menu page besides it showing the original content for the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is here:

```
if( get_page_by_slug($slug) ){
}wp_redirect('https://example.com/private-page/'.$slug.'/');
exit;
```

The `if()` statement will do nothing; your `wp_redirect()` and `exit` statements are outside the `{}` braces.

Try this instead:

```
 if( get_page_by_slug($slug) ){
    wp_redirect('https://example.com/private-page/'.$slug.'/');
    exit;
 }
```

Aside from that, a couple other things to check:

- You say the code is in `function.php`; if you're referring to a theme file, it needs to be `functions.php` (note the `s`) in the currently-active theme.
- Where are these functions being called from? What action/filter hook are you adding them to?

Comment: I actually had already fixed that if() statement problem and it didn't fix the problem. It was a mistype on myself to put "function.php" I actually did it on functions.php.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to when you ask where are the functions being called from and what action/filter hook I am adding to them. I am new to php so sorry if I am unfamiliar with some of the objects/controls that are used in the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just introducing functions to `functions.php` won't result in your code being run. You'll need to hook them into WordPress somewhere, almost always by using an [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) or a [filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

Comment: Which hook should I use and do I just add it in the same code?

Comment: I figured it out a few hours ago by using "template_redirect" thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.